# How to count input value length in typescript(Angular)?

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to count form control value in reactive form..

```
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="PreMobile" (keypress)="keyPress($event)" (focusout)="validation()"/>
          </div>
```

This is my Form Control Name.

Form Name is **memberApplicationForm**

Form Initialization

```
private initializeForm() {
    this.memberApplicationForm = new FormGroup({
      PreMobile: new FormControl(''),
    });
```

Now I want to count PreMobile formcontrol input value length.

```
  validation(){
    // What should be here
  }
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the work:

```
validation() {
   console.log(this.memberApplicationForm.controls.PreMobile.value.length);
}
```

On the form object we can access its controls with their respective values. Try logging this like above and use it as you intended.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this,

```
validation() {
   console.log(this.memberApplicationForm.get('PreMobile').value.length);
}
```